# Generating a map of strings to std::list of pointers in c++

Tags: c++, stl

I am trying to achieve the creation of such a map. The following code attempts to do this

```
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <string>

class IntWithString {
private:
  int a;
  std::string s;

public:
  IntWithString(int a, std::string s) : a(a), s(s) {}
  std::string getString() { return s; }
  int getInt() { return a; }
};

namespace {
std::map<std::string, std::list<IntWithString *> > m;
}

void appendMap(IntWithString *a) {
  auto it = m.find(a->getString());
  if (it != m.end()) {
    m[a->getString()].push_back(a);
  } else {
    std::list<IntWithString *> l;
    l.push_back(a);
    m[a->getString()] = l;
  }
}

int main() {
  IntWithString a(10, "ten");
  IntWithString b(11, "ten");
  appendMap(&a);
  appendMap(&b);
  return 0;
}
```

However when looking at the map m with the debugger I am getting a map that maps "ten" to a list of size 0. What I would like is a list of size 2.

Comment: Do you really want a `std::list<IntWithString *>`?  Generally you do not want to store pointers in a standard container, and if you do, generally you should use a smart pointer so that the container can manage it's lifetime.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem with MS VS 2017. `m` consists of a single element with list of two pointers as a value.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to achieve here, but the code behaves correctly.

Comment: Of topic but... doesn't your `appendMap` implementation basically reduce to `m[a->getString()].push_back(a);` since  `m[a->getString()]` will default construct an `std::list<IntWithString *>` if an entry doesn't already exist for the key in question?

Comment: Have you considered using `std::multimap` here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean. If I do:

```
std::cout << m.size() << ", " << m["ten"].size() << std::endl;
```

I get this output:

> 1, 2

which is a map with one key ("ten"), and two values for that key (10 and 11), as expected.

<kbd>[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/N1ZmYUwx86rF8hX3)</kbd>

PS: Storing pointers in a container like this is a bit uncommon in C++. If you really want to do this though, consider to use [Smart Pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one).

Comment: Ok, this is strange. I get the same output as you. BUT lldb tells me that it is a map with one key and a the sizeof the list is zero.

Comment: @HMPARTICLE strange indeed, however I do not know why, and I am about to board my flight. Sorry.